# LUA / URL Query Parsing

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

How do I serialize the following url with lua?
Is it possible with the "match"?

```
http://example.com/go.php?user=stack&pass=overflow
```

Domain: example.com
User: stack
Pass: overflow

Comment: you mean how to deserialize or parse that url

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s="http://example.com/go.php?user=stack&pass=overflow"
d,u,p=s:match("http://(.+)/.*user=(.-)&pass=(.+)")
print(d,u,p)
```

Comment: `http://example.com/go.php?pass=overflow&user=stack` That should work as well, but wouldn't in this case.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer, indeed.But the OP hasn't indicate whether to expect this.